# Making a moving object in bash shell

Tags: bash, unix, new-operator

So basically I need a function that will create an object and move it down the screen at a certain rate(1 line per second for now). The end product that this will be going to is a space invader type game in the command prompt.

I have no clue how to get this started besides a variable and an echo statement. I wanna know how to make that statement move down the screen until it disappears.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of the different curses applications - here is one that allows you to do all sorts of things like progress bars, tables, colors, etc. - if you are open to python, check it out https://github.com/Textualize/rich

There is ncurses - https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-ncurses-widgets-in-shell-scripts-on-linux

There is also... https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/colorizing.html